# Why doesn't php throw undefined offset notice for an offset on interger/null/boolean values?

Tags: php, error-handling, offset, notice

For any of the following cases, there is no undefined offset notice or any kind of notice:

```
$var1 = true;
$var2 = $var1[4];

$var1 = null;
$var2 = $var1[4];

$var1 = 1234;
$var2 = $var1[4];
```

All of these cases are invalid codes and one would expect PHP to throw some kind of notice.
Is there a reason for not throwing error or is this just of those PHP weirdness?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: php allows you to access a string like an array with the [] syntax